# Wordpress Site takes almost a minute to load

Tags: wordpress, performance, pagespeed

I have been working on this wordpress site for a company and it takes almost a minute to load and I am not exactly sure why. The site itself is not that big and I am just sort of lost as to where to look. They use godaddy as hosting so I can't troubleshoot the site on staging because it always breaks the main site upon transfer. I am also not proficient with php, and as previously stated just sort of lost as to where to look. Any advise would be greatly apreciated.

the site is https://prestige-ballroom.com/

Comment: Using Chrome / Firefox; Right click, Inspect, then do a hard refresh of the page and watch the resources that load. You seem to have two resources that fail with 500's, that take 20s+ before they fail.

Answer (score 0):

[TTFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_To_First_Byte) is too big. Try install plugin for caching content, I would recommend WP Super Cache.

Comment: they use godaddy who claims to have their own cache process so you can't install any such plugins through their hosting

Comment: also the purpose of the site is to convert first time visitors so they wouldn't have anything cached anyway. But I looked at the waterfall and see what you are saying. Now just to find a way to fix it

Comment: So hosting the king. The good hosting worths thousands optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

You're loading over 7mb of data on the homepage. Compress everything and reduce file sizes as much as possible. You're using full size PNGs for some thumbnails, for instance. A few of those are > 1mb on their own, e.g. [this one](https://prestige-ballroom.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/andre-hunter-181730-e1490564302504.png).

You'll be able to drastically speed up the full load time of the site by doing so.

However, the real core of the issue here – the reason the site *feels* so slow – is due to your TTFB, as Alex has said.

Take a look at this breakdown just for that image I linked above:

[image: Image Download]

More than half of the time spent downloading that image was just waiting for the first byte to be returned by the server. I think it's time to get off of GoDaddy.

Here's an even more egregious example:

[image: File Download]

That's a JS file only a few kilobytes in size, but the download doesn't even begin for over a full second.

Comment: thanks I have tried to compress the images but it didn't seem to help a whole lot, but ill give it another go. also if you have a recomended size for images.

Comment: and trust me go daddy is the bain of my existence. Worst service I have ever come across

Comment: my biggest concern right now is that it doen't seem to be consistent. sometimes the test is less than 3 seconds. sometimes its over 30.